# Why does this Excel VBA script copy downwards and repeat till the last selected cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Why does this copy data down to the next blank cell till the next full cell, then take that cell's data and start over again?

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyDown()

    Dim wsPOD As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow

    Set wsPOD = Sheets("PO Data")

With wsPOD
    lastrow = wsPOD.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wsPOD.Range("A2:D" & lastrow).Select
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
            Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    End With
End Sub
```

I understand the majority of the script, but I don't understand this part:

```
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
        Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
```

The last part especially means gibberish to me, can someone help me understand this please?

Comment: The range `wsPOD.Range("A2:D" & lastrow)` is selected. Within that range blank/empty cells are selected using `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select`. Then in the blank cells the formula `"=R[-1]C"` is entered to set the cell to the cell above. Essentially your filling down any blank cells with the cell contents above. I'd remove the select/Selection statements as they're not needed.

Comment: The sheet is six columns wide, only four of them I want this code to run. In this case, how would you do it, because I need a limit of how far down it goes too.

Comment: It only works in four currently A:D - "A2:D" & lastrow

Comment: To add to @ooo comments, `=R[-1]C` is R1C1 notation. It says set the formula of the cell equal to the cell 1 row above 'R[-1]' it and 0 columns `C` from it. R1C1 can be very handy at times in code instead of normal notation. When you see the result in excel for, say B2, it will have `=B1` inside the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my comment you can tidy up the code using

Option Explicit

```
Sub CopyDown()

    Dim wsPOD As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow as long
    Dim EmptyCells as range

    Set wsPOD = Sheets("PO Data")

With wsPOD
    lastrow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            set EmptyCells = .Range("A2:D" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            EmptyCells.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I like the code :) sweet and simple, and does exactly what I need. Thanks... but also thanks for explaining what it does.